# How to update View from callbacks from a given viewController in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `state` `String` variable called `fullLogMessages`

In my `ViewController` I set the `fullLogMessage` through given callbacks. This `fulllogMessage` I then get from a LogViewModel I created

I can get it to update a TextField on a button click to add a request has been sent, but unsure how to update the Textfield for the subsequent callbacks.

SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI
struct TestAdsView: View {
    @StateObject var lvm: LogsViewModel = LogsViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(vm.adStatus.rawValue)
            TextField("Logs", text: $lvm.getFullLogMessage)
            Button("load Ads", action: {
                vm.loadAds()
            })
             AdsScreenView_UI(viewModel: vm).frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }
}

struct AdsScreenView_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: AdsScreenViewModel
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some AdsScreenViewController {
        print(#function)
        return AdsScreenViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

I'm a bit stuck on how I can get the TextField to update from getting the message in the `updateUIViewController`. This method gets called after each callback but no idea how to update the view with the given message.

Comment: You need an `@Published` property in your `LogsViewModel` which your view can use.  You can either provide the instance of that view model to `AdsScreenView_UI` so that it can call a method to update the log or you could use `NotificationCenter` and post an event

Comment: I have it as '@Published property' in the 'LogsViewModel'. I also have an instance of it in the 'AdScreenView_UI'. The problem is how can I get it to update the 'TextField' without some action like pressing a button or something?

Comment: If it is an `@Published` property then you can simply bind to that value in your view as you have done; When the value changes SwiftUI uses Combine to refresh the view.  What you haven't shown is how you update `getFullLogMessage` - You have `lvm` and `vm` but you haven't shown where `vm` comes from nor how it is related to `lvm`

Comment: If it is done rapidly upon appearing you might have to delay the update using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {` or something similar.

Comment: @loremipsum you are a star, it worked. Thank you